# does fascinating have a positive connotation?

Tags: american-english

I just wanted to know because I am curious I was just wondering does it have a negative connotation or a positive connotation or both or just a negative connotation.

Comment: It usually implies a certain attractiveness.  This may be negative if it's, say, drawing flies, but usually is positive.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In a strict sense *fascinating* has a neutral connotation.  Its usage is synonymous with *interesting*, both meaning engaging. Insofar as *engaging*, as in worth spending time on, has a positive connotation, then so do *fascinating* and *interesting*.

*Fascinating*, like *interesting*, is often used as a tactful euphemism for a negative connotation.
Like, "That's an interesting outfit,"  or 
"What do you think of that painting?" "It's...fascinating."

Recall the venerable Chinese anathema:  "May you live in *interesting* times."

Comment: I think the example you give assumes the speaker would adopt an ironic tone to imply the negative connotation. In this case, any positive attribute can be used as a negative. "Your example is so... correct". What this demonstrates is that fascinating has positive connotations, and the use of irony just reverses that, because irony.

Comment: I don't understand the hostility to the answer.  I said it has a neutral to positive connotation.  Of course "any" positive attribute can be used as a negative, but "interesting" and "fascinating" have popular usages in particular, as I describe.  That has nothing to do with irony.  Tact and euphemism are the words I used, not irony.  That's what you and the down votes attribute speciously to what I''m saying.

Comment: something that fascinates is not neutral

Comment: I think the down votes are because the answer is perceived to be wrong, there's nothing personal or hostile about it, please don't take it that way.
Tactful euphemism is itself a euphemism for lying, i.e. saying the opposite of what you mean, and once again, any positive attribute could be used as such.